# Why AMI creation is taking long time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a AMI from an instance with a root device of 160GB in size. This root volume is of type `io1` with an iops of 1250.

In my AWs account, creating an AMI takes about 5 minutes. This is with data about more than 100GB.

On the customer's AWS account, the same configuration takes over 20+ minutes.

I have tested this with many repetitions and I get almost similar results all time.

Any idea why the AMI creation varies so much between multiple AWS accounts?

Answer (score 3):

An AMI consists of **snapshots** of Amazon EBS volumes attached to the instance.

Snapshots consist of **"differences" from the previous snapshot** (including the original AMI that was used to launch the instance).

For example, if you were to launch a new instance from an AMI and then immediately create a new AMI from the instance, **very little data would have changed** on the disk volume. Thus, the AMI and its underlying snapshot would be very quick to create.

If, over time, a lot of information was added/modified on the disk volume(s), then creating an AMI will take longer because more disk blocks have changed.

Creating Snapshots and AMIs can be made faster by **taking more frequent snapshots**, since this will copy modified blocks to Amazon S3. Thus, each successive snapshot/AMI will require fewer blocks to be copied.

The speed of a snapshot/AMI is **not impacted by the assigned IOPS to a volume**. The snapshot process takes place in the back-end, which does not consume the IOPS allocated to a volume.